# Is there a way to run a regression between 2 variables in different datasets?

Tags: r, csv, dataset, regression, linear-regression

I was just curious if there was a way to run a regression between two different datasets without pulling the variables you want out and putting them into a new matrix.

If there isn't it's fine, but I figured that there might be a way to do so

Comment: Are you asking if you can do this `lm(df$y ~ df$x)`, or are you asking if you can simultaneously fit regression models to `y ~ x` in `df1` and `z ~ w` in `df2`?

Comment: lm(df$y ~ df$x), I'm sorry if that question wasn't clear enough

Comment: Okay - so it's perfectly okay to write `fit = lm(df1$y ~ df2$x)` (sorry I omitted the different data frame names in my question). You don't need to pull them out of their individual data frames and make a new one.

Comment: Ok so I tried, is there any reason why I'm getting the error message:                     
`Error in model.frame.default(formula = df2008_only_county$`Average Age` ~ : variable lengths differ(found for 'df2007_only_county$`Total Actual Costs`')`

Comment: Pretty much because of what the answer below says - the data frames have to have the same number of rows otherwise the model fitting makes no sense - "for every y, there must be a matching x, otherwise trying to describe the relationship between y and x doesn't mean anything"

Answer (score 0):

If DF1 and DF2 are the two data frames having the same number of rows (if they don't have the same number of rows the question does not make sense) then we can do any of these.  The first 3 specify DF1 and/or DF2 in the formula.  The last 2 use the formula y ~ x and use other means to tell it where to look.

```
lm(DF1$y ~ x, DF2)

lm(y ~ DF2$x, DF1)

lm(DF1$y ~ DF2$x)  # mentioned in comments under question

# in this one it looks into DF1 first and if not found looks into DF2
with(DF2, lm(y ~ x, DF1))

lm(y ~ x, cbind(DF1, DF2))
```